# Make the official WPF RibbonTextBox look like a PasswordBox

Tags: wpf, ribbon, passwordbox

I'm developing an application with the official WPF Ribbon system, and I'd like to have a password field up in the ribbon. Is there any way I can modify the RibbonTextBox control to display dots instead of characters, the way a PasswordBox does? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have to ask . . . why on earth would you have a password field in the ribbon?

Comment: I'm making a super-simple program that has all of the interactive controls up in the ribbon and the remainder of the application area is basically a console. You need to log into a website, hence the password field. It's not the end of the world by any stretch if it's too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use the key up event, and take the value out of the box, store it in a variable, and replace it with the character you want?

User presses "A" on key up, you grab the value, store it in a variable, and then replace it with an "*". Keep doing this until they stop typing in the box?